# Hide First TableView Section header height iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

< iOS 11 below code works to hide the tableView Section Height for the first section.

```
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 20.0
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-18.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

For iOS 11 what should works?
I tried setting section 0 to 'nil' from `titleForHeaderInSection` and heightForHeaderInSection to '0' for first section but it didn't work.

Comment: Try to set section header height = 0.1

Comment: how many sections you have?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini 3

Comment: `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0.01))` try this

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

**This alone will not show a section header:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}
```

**This will show a section header with no title:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The follow method is invalid in iOS11

> 1.controller.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

You can use follow method to replace

> 2.controller.view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;

if it still doesn't work maybe you can write follow code

> 3.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView.init();